# Launch VSCode from source through WSL

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to build/launch the VSCode source code in the native Bash for Windows client.  I have followed the steps [outlined in the VSCode wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run-from-source) on how to contribute, and everything is working as expected (All commands have been run on the WSL terminal following the Linux instructions)

After running `yarn run watch`, I try to launch VSCode by running `DISPLAY=:0 ./scripts/code.sh` from the source code directory, but nothing happens.  I get two duplicate warnings:

`[21496:1128/120229.392130:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(295)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected`

but I'm not sure if this is causing the problem.  I have an X Server client running, and have used to to successfully launch native Windows applications through WSL (terminator, emacs, etc.)

Is what I'm trying to do possible?  If so, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Amazing that you asked this! I was attempting to do the *exact same thing* at (it seems) the *exact same time*. Here's my process.

1. Install XMing
2. Install the xfree apps
3. Set DISPLAY=:0
4. Run `xeyes` ==> Awesome googly eyes!
5. Attempt to build vscode from source. The [build docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run-from-source) seem to be incomplete b/c I had to install a ton of libraries beyond those listed e.g.

`yarn
  gulp
  gulp-cli
  pkg-config
  libx11-dev
  libxkbfile-dev
  libsecret-1-dev
  libgtk2.0-dev
  libxss-dev
  gnome-dev
  libgconf2-dev
  libnss3-dev
  libasound2-dev`

Eventually get the `yarn` tasks to finish such that I could run `code.sh`

`./scripts/code.sh
[20474:1128/153959.035267:ERROR:bus.cc(427)] Failed to connect to the bus: F
ailed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or
directory
[20474:1128/153959.081986:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(295)] Multiple instances
of AudioManager detected
[20474:1128/153959.082101:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(254)] Multiple instances
of AudioManager detected`

Looking at `ps` I see that the process was running.

### Conjectures

It seems that building from source from WSL is not yet supported. Or maybe you can build the artifact, but you can't connect to the Windows display to show it. Based on the quality of the `xeyes` session, it looks like a very, very, **very** primitive experience e.g. still using WinXP-style minimize / maximize / close icons.

I was *literally* writing an Issue on their github page when I thought I'd do *one last search* and found this post. Much of vscode treats WSL as a second-class environment on Windows. Recent work seems to suggest that things are going to get better as driving to integration between Windows' two internal environments continues to improve (e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/39144)

### Update 2017-11-30

Based on some pursuit via Github, it seems that this issue has been reported to the WSL team: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2293. It appears to be under active consideration by the WSL team. I've added some commentary about my use case there.

Comment: Always great to hear when someone shares the same problem!  My process was very similar, and I concur with the overall WSL experience.  I'm definitely hanging in there though, windows+ubuntu would be the dream.

Comment: @taylorstine I tried to capture our experience in a useful PR: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/39286